# How to pass more parameter to ashx asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ashx, form-data

About this, i founded more time , but seem it's not working. I have 2 textbox and 1 file input, and i want to upload some info and file(image). This is my code snippet. First in file .ashx

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
string text1 = context.Request["text1_temp"];
string number = context.Request["number_temp"];
HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
/////something 
}
```

And .aspx file

```
var files = $("#inputfile").get(0).files;
var test = new FormData();
///// only 1 file image
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
test.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
}
///// add more parameter
test.append($("#txt_text1").val(), "text1_temp");
test.append($("#txt_number").val(), "number_temp");

if(!isImage($("#inputfile").val())){
alert("Not file Image");
return false;
}
else{
$.ajax({
url: "UploadPaper.ashx",
type: "POST",
contentType: false,
processData: false,
data: test,
success: function (result) {
console.log(result);
},
error: function (err) {
console.log(err.statusText);
}
});
return true;
}
```

Ok, look seem work, but when i run and debug at `string text1 = context.Request["text1_temp"];string number = context.Request["number_temp"];` data text1 and number is null .
Can you tell me what problem or mistake in here ? and how to fix it ? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Anybody some idea ?.Share with me.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are sending one object, not different parameters.

Instead you may use:

```
data: "{text1_temp: 'myValue',number_temp: '0'}",
```

Comment: Oh, I try this ago , but seem it's not work. Please notes, `var test = new FormData();` and `data: test,` .